# For Loop not filtering through each cell in column

Tags: vba, for-loop

[image]

Right now I have a table where each individual put a ranking 1-5 for their most applicable traits.

I'm trying to create a table which I can manipulate via pivot table & I'm trying to construct that table via vba

What I have successfully done so far is take each members, name and create a column which lists 1-5. What I need to do is loop through each row in the first image, and do a match function for each ranking to see what is the column number of each rank in each row. Then I need to input that number into my second image under category location.

What's happening so far is it's only doing that for some of my rows.
It's only doing it for 173 rows which is the number of rows in the first image/table

[image]

[image]

However, I have modified the code so it should be doing a match function  for (173 * 5) rows. I'm not sure why it's not doing it for every row just stopping at 173

```
Sub StructurePivot2()
Dim X As Variant, Var As Double, P As Integer, Z As Integer, ws As Worksheet, rng3 As Range, category As Variant, rng As Range, cell As Variant, i As Integer, rng2 As Range
Set ws = Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set rng = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A2:A173")
Set rng2 = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B2:AI2")
Set rng3 = rng2.Offset(P)
For Each cell In rng
    Set rng3 = rng2.Offset(P)
        Debug.Print rng3.Address
    For i = 1 To 5

        Z = Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(i, rng3, 0)
        Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A3").Offset(P, 10) = Z
        P = P + 1
    Next i
    P = 0
Next cell
End Sub
```

Comment: It's stopping at 173 because that's what your outer For Each loop tells it to do .... Change 4th line ?   Your for i= 1 to 5 is not extending the "for each" loop to 173*5

Comment: Could not clearly understood what you want to achieve, But `rng3` is always "B2:AI2" as You are making P=0 before `Next cell`. Also P=P+1 has also has no effect on rng3 as it is inside `For i=1 to 5` loop (P is only causing sheet2 destination offset change)